# System Configuration of a standalone Hadoop cluster

Tags: apache, hadoop, cluster-computing, hortonworks-data-platform

I am going to set up a standalone Hortonworks cluster. 
What is the needed system configuration that could process 1TB of data.

Requirement such as:

1. RAM space
2. Hard disk space
3. quad-/hex-/octo-core CPUs running how much GHZ
4. Cent os which version etc.,

Answer (score 1):

System Configuration depends on the usecase.
Disk - Assuming 1 replication, 1 TB + 25% processing space

If you are using Hive or MapReduce I would start with 16 Gig, 4 or 8 core. CentOS 7.0